# How to align sorting image with DataTable's column header in datatable definition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I created a page with datatable. However, when datatable is displayed, sorting images appear on the next line:

[image]

This is how table is defined:

```
$("#tblTable").dataTable(
    {
        "sDom": 't<"F"i>',
        "aoColumns": [
            {"sWidth": "17%", "sType": "string", "bSortable": true },  
            {"sWidth": "10%", "sType": "string", "bSortable": true }, 
            {"sWidth": "15%", "sType": "string", "bSortable": true },  
            {"sWidth": "58%", "sType": "string", "bSortable": false}                   
        ],
        "sScrollY": "180px",
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "aaSorting": [],
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bJQueryUI": true
    });
```

Is that possible to fix it inside of the table defenition?

Comment: You need to adjust the `sWidth` value. This corresponds to the percentage of the total width of the table that the column uses. In your case, go with 15 or 20 instead of 10%.

Comment: As you see, I have 15% and 17% in the first and the third column and it did not work. I also tried that before posting this question and it did not fix the problem

Comment: Your image has 3 columns and the code indicates there are four. What's missing?

Comment: Also, you're using an older version of datatables that isn't full supported. I'd consider upgrading and you'll get some additional features like dynamically sizing the table

Comment: There are 4 columns, I just displayed ones that need to be sorted.

Comment: The application I'm working on is using this version for now. So, it is not a priority now to upgrade the datatable. I want to find the solution for the current version

Comment: In that case, the 10% applies the the second column with "Created by" not the 15% or 17%.

Comment: I have changed the widths to 20% and 25% for the first and second columns but it did not make any difference

Comment: When you made column 2 larger, did you make the others smaller? It's possible that the table itself is too narrow and the smallest column will always be cut off like this. Just for testing, make the second column the widest (51%) and see what happens.

Comment: Just tried that. It did not solve the problem. I think the issue is not in the width but in something else

Answer (score 0):

Yes...you can adjust the percentage of the total that each column uses like so:

```
"aoColumns": [
            {"sWidth": "15%", "sType": "string", "bSortable": true},  
            {"sWidth": "15%", "sType": "string", "bSortable": true }, 
            {"sWidth": "15%", "sType": "string", "bSortable": true },  
            {"sWidth": "55%", "sType": "string", "bSortable": false}                   
        ],
```

Looks like your second column was just a little too narrow at 10%.

Alternatively, you can remove all the `sWdith` settings and switch `bAutoWidth` to `true` (`"bAutoWidth": true,`)

Comment: Actually, I had these exact settings in the beginning, before posting the question and it did not help

Comment: @gene See my addition to original answer.

Comment: May be there is some css way to define styles when datatable is defined?

Comment: Did you try this: `"bAutoWidth": false,`

Comment: Yes, take as look at my original post. This was defined even before I specified width values

Comment: Sorry...meant `"bAutoWidth": true,`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
Basically, when the datatable is rendered, the sort arrow section is representing by `span` area:
`<span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s" style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;"`

I had to add `$('.ui-icon').css('display', 'inline-block')` to the datatable definition.

That fixed it for me.

Hope that will help someone.